# JQuery UI inline DatePicker loses selected date after ASP.NET postback, How to keep it?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, datepicker

I have a jQuery datepicker and the code is as below:

```
 <div id="test"></div>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtRDate" runat="server" Width="120px"  ClientIDMode="Static"  AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="txtRDate_TextChanged">
 </asp:TextBox>
```

Javascript code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#test').datepicker({
dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
minDate: new Date(2017, 1, 1),
defaultDate: new Date(),

onSelect: function(date, obj){
$('#txtRDate').val(date);  //Updates value of date
$('#txtRDate').trigger('change');
}
});
</script>
```

When select date from datepicker the TextChanged for textbox fired and do postback.

c# Code behind:

```
     protected void txtRDate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        GetData(txtRDate.Text);
     }
```

JQuery UI inline DatePicker loses selected date after ASP.NET postback, How to keep it?

Thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyK7U.png)

Comment: I have added the jsfiddle link in your post can you explain what exactly is going wrong in that?

Comment: @ Vijendra Kulhade How to keep jquiry datepicker with date value selected after auto postback event (txtRDate_TextChanged)?

Comment: Why is the date picker a different object than the textbox?  I changed #test to #txtRDate and it posted through just fine on my aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

I made some minor changes and it all works in my test environment.
I added the moments.js (http://momentjs.com ) lib and used it to initialized the date to the current date if the text box was not empty.

Made some minor changes to the jQuery, particularly the target element.
The second text box was added only to see that the server was it by concatenation "1" each time it hit.

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="LaptopWeb.test" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                if ($("#txtRDate").val() == "") {
                    $("#txtRDate").val(moment().format("YYYY/MM/DD"))
                }
                $('#txtRDate').datepicker({

                    dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
                    minDate: new Date(2017, 1, 1),
                    onSelect: function(date, obj){
                      $('#txtRDate').trigger('change');
                    }
                });
            });
        </script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtRDate" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCount" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

server side:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

    namespace LaptopWeb
    {
        public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                txtCount.Text = txtCount.Text + " 1";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

its worked with some minor changes:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#test').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
        minDate: new Date(2017, 1, 1),
        defaultDate: $('#txtRDate').val(),
        onSelect: function (date, obj) {
            $('#txtRDate').val(date);  //Updates value of date
            //Add the value to hidden field
            $('#HiddenField1').val(date);
            $('#txtRDate').trigger('change');
            
           
        }
        
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Assign the value from hidden field to textbox
     onLoad:   $('#txtRDate').val($('#HiddenField1').val());
    });
</script>
```